# Moving a large set of numbers to a new range in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm having conflicting numbers in one of my configurations. This wouldn't be a problem except this range of numbers is over 150 (this being affected is between 700-1000, with random unoccupied IDs).

My setup has been set up to suggest open ranges for these conflicting IDs, 3739-3852, 596,699, and 1617-1719.

How would I move these conflicting IDs to these open ranges? (ie 700 -> 3739 and so forth with the consecutive numbers)

An example is this:

```
ConflictingIDOne=700
ConflictingIDTwo=701
...
ConflictingIDxxx=1000
```

and I want to move it to

```
ConflictingIDOne=3739
ConflictingIDTwo=3740
...
ConflictingIDXXX=3852
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and mark the numbers with the mouse (colum/block select)
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This should open the Block-Edit dialog
3. Select 'insert numbers' and insert as first number 3739 and increase by 1

I hope you can find what I mean. I have the german version and do not know if it is labled as I written here.

Comment: Thank you, this does work. I did have to align my assigned IDs for the variables for it to properly replace (it would break the text since they're of different charsizes), but it did do its job after that.